# Merge/group array values to stop duplicated parents with exactly the same fullname

Tags: php, arrays

```
$temp = [];
$array = [];

$array[] = array("parent_id" => 1, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs Lacey", "child_firstname" => "callum", "child_lastname" => "lacey");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 2, "parent" => "Mr and Mrs Lacey", "child_firstname" => "daniel", "child_lastname" => "lacey");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 3, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs O'brian", "child_firstname" => "bruce", "child_lastname" => "O'brian");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 4, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs Obrian", "child_firstname" => "dave", "child_lastname" => "O'brian");


function stripString($input){
    $input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $input);
    return $input;
}

foreach($array as $item){
    $input = str_replace(" and ","", $item["parent"]);
    $parent = stripString($input);
    $child_firstname = stripString($item["child_firstname"]);
    $child_lastname = stripString($item["child_lastname"]);
    $temp[] = array("parent_id" => $item["parent_id"], 
                    "parent" => $parent, 
                    "child_firstname" => $child_firstname, 
                    "child_lastname" => $child_lastname);
}
```

Print out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [parent] => MrMrsLacey
            [child_firstname] => callum
            [child_lastname] => lacey
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 2
            [parent] => MrMrsLacey
            [child_firstname] => daniel
            [child_lastname] => lacey
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 3
            [parent] => MrMrsObrian
            [child_firstname] => bruce
            [child_lastname] => Obrian
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 4
            [parent] => MrMrsObrian
            [child_firstname] => dave
            [child_lastname] => Obrian
        )
)
```

What I want to be able to print out: (needs to should the `duplicated_id`)

```
Array (
    [0] => Array  (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [duplicated_id] => 2
            [parent] => MrMrsLacey
            [0] => Array (
                [child_firstname] => callum
                [child_lastname] => lacey
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [child_firstname] => daniel
                [child_lastname] => lacey
            )
        )

    [1] => Array (
            [parent_id] => 3
            [duplicated_id] => 4
            [parent] => MrMrsObrian
            [0] => Array (
                [child_firstname] => bruce
                [child_lastname] => Obrian
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [child_firstname] => dave
                [child_lastname] => Obrian
            )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add values to index based array and then reset it: [Eval](https://eval.in/666069)

```
<?php

$temp = [];
$array = [];

$array[] = array("parent_id" => 1, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs Lacey", "child_firstname" => "callum", "child_lastname" => "lacey");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 2, "parent" => "Mr and Mrs Lacey", "child_firstname" => "daniel", "child_lastname" => "lacey");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 3, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs O'brian", "child_firstname" => "bruce", "child_lastname" => "O'brian");
$array[] = array("parent_id" => 4, "parent" => "Mr & Mrs Obrian", "child_firstname" => "dave", "child_lastname" => "O'brian");


function stripString($input){
    $input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]+/", "", $input);
    return $input;
}

foreach($array as $item){
    $input = str_replace(" and ","", $item["parent"]);
    $parent = stripString($input);
    $child_firstname = stripString($item["child_firstname"]);
    $child_lastname = stripString($item["child_lastname"]);

    if(!array_key_exists($parent, $temp)) {  //Add only first index details to array
        $temp[$parent]['parent_id'] = $item["parent_id"];
        $temp[$parent]['parent'] = $parent;
    } else {
        $temp[$parent]['duplicated_id'] = $item["parent_id"];
    }

    // Remove unwanted indices
    $temp[$parent][] = array("child_firstname" => $child_firstname, 
        "child_lastname" => $child_lastname);        

}

$temp = array_values($temp);  // Reset index

print_r($temp);
```

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 1
            [parent] => MrMrsLacey
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [child_firstname] => callum
                    [child_lastname] => lacey
                )

            [duplicated_id] => 2
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [child_firstname] => daniel
                    [child_lastname] => lacey
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 3
            [parent] => MrMrsObrian
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [child_firstname] => bruce
                    [child_lastname] => Obrian
                )

            [duplicated_id] => 4
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [child_firstname] => dave
                    [child_lastname] => Obrian
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Check my updated question, it needs to also show the `duplicated_ids`

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Check out. Updated! But what if when more than one id is duplicated? as an array or comma separated?

Comment: what would you recommend? which would be better an array or comma separated?

Comment: It depends on your need. If you reuse those values go for array, or if it is just for display purpose comma separated is enough

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with the array

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with indexing the new array by parent ID (which shouldn't matter) you can do something like this:

```
foreach($array as $delta => $item){
  [...]
  $temp[$item['parent_id']]['parent_id'] = $item["parent_id"];
  $temp[$item['parent_id']]['parent'] = $item["parent"];

  $temp[$item['parent_id']][$delta] = array(
    "child_firstname" => $child_firstname, 
    "child_lastname" => $child_lastname);
  );
}
```

This should result in the parent's `parent_id` and `parent` keys getting overwritten repeatedly but that doesn't matter; the result should be what you want.

If possible though, I'd nest the children under their own key, to allow for easy iteration. At the moment to iterate children you'll have to test each key to make sure it's numeric!

Comment: Check my updated question, it needs to also show the `duplicated_ids`

Comment: What is `duplicated_ids` supposed to represent? I can't figure it out from that description.